# Append Option in Select on change in Multiselect

Tags: javascript, arrays, ajax, for-loop, append

I use jQuery to append Options in select tag. I append options on basis of a multiselect tag.
Here is my code
HTML
Multiselect

```
<select multiple="multiple" class="form-control kt-selectpicker" name="ranch[]" id="ranch" onchange="multiRanchFields()">
       @foreach ($ranches as $ranch)
         <option value={{ $ranch->id }} selected>{{ $ranch->ranch_name }}</option>
      @endforeach
  </select>
```

Other Select

```
 <select class="form-control kt-selectpicker" name="meeting_ranch_location" id="meeting_ranch_location">
      <option></option>
 </select>
```

JavaScript

```
        function multiRanchFields() {
            var count = $('#ranch option:selected').length;
            var ranch_ids = $('#ranch').val();
            for (let id = 0; id < ranch_ids.length; id++) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: `/get_ranch_name/${ranch_ids[id]}`,
                    method: 'GET',
                    data: ranch_ids[id],
                    success: function(response) {
                        $("#meeting_ranch_location").append('<option value=' + ranch_ids[id] + '>' + response.name +
                            '</option>');
                    }
                });
            }
            $("#meeting_ranch_location").selectpicker('refresh');
        }
```

But what it does is it appends more options than one...For example if I select one option it does not append any options. When I select two options is appends 1 option and when I select 3 it appends 3  options but two of them are same and one is new...and when I select 4 options There are 6 options appended and only One is unique...

What I want to do is to append as many options as many are selected in multiselect new appended options will have same names selected in multiselect

Comment: Can you add all this code to a working snippet with the full URL so we can test with your code as we troubleshoot?

Comment: Thanks for your reply.. But I solved this by making select tag empty and then refresh after new changes...

Comment: Glad to hear it!